# How to get the switch() funciton to say more than one value when two values are the same

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I don't know if you consider that excel is a valid programming language to ask in there, but I need this for a project.

[image: Example]

In the switch() function, I said to compare the max value of those cells to return the one that coincides, but when two values are the same, it returns the one who is first.

```
=SWITCH(MAX(J3:J7);J3;"Jugador 1";J4;"Jugador 2";J5;"Jugador 3";J6;"Jugador 4";J7;"Jugador 5")
```

How could I make it to return "Jugador 2, Jugador 3" instead of just one of them?

I don't figure what function can do something like that. I thought of making something like to functions in one but don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome!

There are several different techniques to accomplish this task. One of them is using a combination of [**TEXTJOIN()**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) and [**IF()**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) functions in [**array formula**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

`{=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(J3:J7=MAX(J3:J7);A3:A7;""))}`